# Julia: how to wipe julia

Tags: julia

How do I completely wipe (remove) Julia from my system?

Comment: What do you mean by 'The code ~/.julia is not working in my julia' ? Is there any error message?

Comment: Do you mean you want to re-install julia or start over with the packages? @tholy below has the best answer for starting over a clean packages directory

Answer (score 20):

Unless you've made changes to the code in packages, you can delete the whole .julia directory when you get into trouble. Either via a file manager, or (on a Unix system) via the command line,

```
rm -rf ~/.julia
```

Answer (score 7):

Tim's answer is good, however you can also be a bit more specific.
I usually do the following (since I'm using v0.5, the path has v0.5, however, that will depend on what version you are using):

```
rm -rf ~/.julia/lib/v0.5 ~/.julia/v0.5/<packagename>
```

Deleting the lib subdirectory gets rid of any precompiled code, which might be also in a bad state.